# firebase integration with flutter not successful with geolocation dependency

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm wondering when I integrate firebase with flutter it works perfect ,
but if I add geolocation package in dependencies :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
geolocation: ^0.2.1
```

I got this message in debug when i compile the project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

Any idea what is going on.?

Comment: These issues https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?q=Unable+to+merge+dex&type=Issues might provide helpful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with indentation.

Try with

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  geolocation: ^0.2.1
```

Comment: After hours of trying to figure it out, My problem was only because of the spacing!
Thank you !!